High AUC on training data but incorrect predictions
I am doing a model that have two outputs: 1 categorical and 1 binary.
After training the model, it has a very high accuracy on training data, and low accuracy on validation data. I wanted to see which images the model got wrong, so I plotted the images as well as its predictions. When I see the model's predictions on the training dataset, all predictions are wrong despite the high AUC (same situation for accuracy). I am using Tensorflow 2.10
The images are inside a folder and there is a CSV file for the labels of the images. The CSV file contains the file path of the images as well. This is my code to load the data:
future_data = pd.read_csv('future_data_2024.csv')
development_data = pd.read_csv('train_data_2024.csv')

image_dir = './Images/'

# Get the file paths for each image record
development_data['FilePath'] = development_data['FileName'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(image_dir, x))
future_data['FilePath'] = future_data['FileName'].apply(lambda x: os.path.join(image_dir, x))

class_encoder = LabelEncoder()
development_data['ClassEncoded'] = class_encoder.fit_transform(development_data['Class'])

# Encode 'MoreThanOnePerson' label as binary
development_data['MoreThanOnePerson'] = development_data['MoreThanOnePerson'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'YES' else 0)

# Initialize OneHotEncoder
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False)

# Fit and transform the 'ClassEncoded' column
class_onehot = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(development_data[['ClassEncoded']])

# Split the data into training, testing and validation
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(development_data, test_size=0.4, random_state=RANDOM_SEED, shuffle=False)
valid_data, test_data = train_test_split(test_data, test_size=0.5, random_state=RANDOM_SEED, shuffle=False)

X_train, y_train_1, y_train_2 = train_data['FilePath'].values, class_onehot[train_data.index], train_data['MoreThanOnePerson']
X_valid, y_valid_1, y_valid_2 = valid_data['FilePath'].values, class_onehot[valid_data.index], valid_data['MoreThanOnePerson']
X_test, y_test_1, y_test_2 = test_data['FilePath'].values, class_onehot[test_data.index], test_data['MoreThanOnePerson']

# Load and preprocess images
# Apply this on X datasets
def load_image(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [WIDTH, HEIGHT])  # Adjust the size as needed
    image = image / 255.0
    return image

def df_to_dataset(array):
    # Create a dataset from the dataframe
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(array)
    return dataset

X_train = df_to_dataset(X_train).map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
X_valid = df_to_dataset(X_valid).map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
X_test = df_to_dataset(X_test).map(load_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

y_train_1 = df_to_dataset(y_train_1)
y_train_2 = df_to_dataset(y_train_2)

y_valid_1 = df_to_dataset(y_valid_1)
y_valid_2 = df_to_dataset(y_valid_2)

y_test_1 = df_to_dataset(y_test_1)
y_test_2 = df_to_dataset(y_test_2)

# Combine the datasets into a single dataset 
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_train, (y_train_1, y_train_2))).shuffle(buffer_size=len(X_train), seed=RANDOM_SEED).batch(32).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
valid_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_valid, (y_valid_1, y_valid_2))).batch(32)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_test, (y_test_1, y_test_2))).batch(32)

This is my model:
class BaselineModel():
    """
    Used to define our multi-output baseline model. This CNN contains 2 branches, 
    one for predicting Class, one for predicting MoreThanOnePerson. 
    Each branch share the same sequence defined in make_default_hidden_layers methid
    """
    def make_default_hidden_layers(self, inputs):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3))(inputs)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(x)
        
        x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

        x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(x)
        
        return x
    
    def build_class_branch(self, inputs, num_classes=40):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(inputs)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax", name="class_output")(x)
        
        return x
    
    def build_person_branch(self, inputs, num_classes=1):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(inputs)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid", name="person_output")(x)
        
        return x
    
    def create_full_model(self, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, classes=[40, 1]):
        input_shape = (height, width, 3)
        inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
        
        shared_sequence = self.make_default_hidden_layers(inputs)
        class_branch = self.build_class_branch(shared_sequence, classes[0])
        person_branch = self.build_person_branch(shared_sequence, classes[1])
        
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[class_branch, person_branch], name="baseline")
        return model

This is my code to visualize the images and the model's predictions:
# Function to preview dataset
def vis_pred(model, dataset, class_encoder):
    # Create a figure with subplots
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20, 4))
    
    # Iterate over the first 5 elements in the dataset
    for i, (image, (label1, label2)) in enumerate(dataset.take(5)):
        axs[i].imshow(image[0].numpy())  # Display the image
        
        # Decode the class label from one-hot encoding if necessary
        class_label = class_encoder.inverse_transform([tf.argmax(label1[0]).numpy()])[0]
        
        # Extract the binary label
        person_label = label2[0].numpy()
        
        # Get model's predictions
        predictions = model.predict(image, verbose=0)
        
        class_pred = class_encoder.inverse_transform([tf.argmax(predictions[0][0], axis=-1)])[0]
        person_pred = predictions[1][0]
        
        # Set the title of the subplot
        axs[i].set_title(f'{class_label} | {"YES" if person_label == 1 else "NO"}')
        axs[i].axis('off')  # Hide axes for better visualization
        
        # Add text for model's predictions
        axs[i].text(0, 0, f'Class: {class_pred} | Person: {"YES" if person_pred > 0.5 else "NO"}')
    
    plt.show()

When I use the vis_pred function vis_pred(baseline, train_dataset, class_encoder), it produce these images
